# Unity UWP FolderPicker Throws Invalid Window Handle Exception

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp

I'm getting the above exception when trying to user the FolderPicker in a UWP Unity App. I have copied the code from a working example but having no success:

```
FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
try
{
    StorageFolder folder = folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync().GetResults();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.Log(e.ToString());
}
```

My assumption is that it doesn't work with Unity UWP, in a similar vein to Unity offering a subset of .NET etc. Can anyone confirm this or am I missing something obvious?

Best,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the capabilities and declarations needed for accessing the files from a folder? This may be the reason for the above error.

To pick files from folder you need to select Pictures Library from Capabilities.
Also under declarations add File Open Picker.

You can find this options in Package.appxmanifest.

Check this for accessing the file from the folder.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions

Comment: Yep, all permissions granted just to be sure when it didn't work.